# IIS 8.5 can't reach Laravel site from other computers on network

Tags: networking, php, iis, iis-8

I am running IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server. I have set up a laravel site which works on the server but not from any other computers on the network. I am new to Laravel so I am not sure if I am missing something but I believe I have set everything else up correctly. I have 2 other sites running, one on 443 (SSL) and another dev site on 8020 and they work fine. I have had this port (8010) working with other dev sites before but now that I have Laravel running on it I get "The Site cannot be reached"

Steps when setting up:

- Added website on IIS running http with the hostname I wanted on port 8010
- bound to the servers local IP (192.168.1.20) (I tried all unassigned as well with no change).
- I opened the port 8010 in the firewall (ran a port sniffer and it came back open)
- Added to my Host's file in sys32/drivers/etc the new host I set up.
- Checked folder permissions and everything is correct

As I said, I can get to the site just fine when I am on the server but from my local machine I get `The site can not be reached`

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious? As I said, I have another dev server up on 8020 and it is running perfectly fine. I can access that 8020 site from any computer on the network and I believe I have done all the same steps when setting up this 8010 site.

Comment: You are accessing from local IP or DNS name?

Comment: I've tried both, DNS name gives me the error above, IP gives me `Bad request, invalid hostname` but I get that for 8020 as well but DNS works for 8020.